# Clarification: Effective temperature, emission temperature, and effective emission temperature

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change

This terminology is quite confusing to me.  Are effective temperature, emission temperature, and effective emission temperature the same thing?  Where does this occur, at the surface, or at some height in the atmosphere?